# Why does code's structure is so different with each CDN in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cdn, unpkg, jsdelivr

I am so confusing about Vue's structure. First time, I learnt from a video by [freeCodeCamp channel on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXpIoQ_rT_c&t=807s).

After that, I found a book to learn

> Getting to Know Vue.js Learn to Build Single Page Applications in Vue from Scratch

by Brett Nelson

The problem I faced was that when I follow the tutorial on YouTube, I used `unpkg` to run and it worked but with the book, they use
`jsdelivr` and when I used the same code with the code I used for `unpkg`, it didn’t work.

I have no idea about what I should learn because 2 tutorials from 2 sources I used were totally different.

Code I use for `unpkg`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Vue 3</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      {{ propertyName }}
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
  <script>
    let app=Vue.createApp({
      data: function(){
        return {
          propertyName: 'Hello from Getting to Know Vue.js!'
        }
      }
    })
    app.mount('#app')
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code I use for `jsdelivr` (it works but doesn't work with the code in `<script>` tag above):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Vue 3</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      {{ propertyName }}
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script>
    let app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        propertyName: 'Hello from Getting to Know Vue.js!'
      }
    });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both codes are doing the same thing at the end, it's a subtle change in syntax. Sorry if it's confusing but understand that it's actually the same thing at the end.

The `jsdelivr` CDN is also using Vue2, while the `unpkg` is using Vue3 hence the small differences in plugin them to the DOM.

I recommend the usage of SFC style anyway tho (with a build tool like Vite): https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-spec.html#sfc-syntax-specification!